# How to keep track of my total liquid capitals

Tags: budget, europe, software

I want to buy a house, so I need to know how much money + stocks I have. I have three "savings": my bank account, a deposit account and some company stocks (I also have some RSU, but I haven't vested them yet, so I can't sell them). Right now, I just wrote the following table in Excel:

| year | source | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | bank account |  |
| 2022 | deposit |  |
|  | total w/o stocks |  |
| 2022 | stocks |  |
|  | total |  |

but I was wondering if there could be better ways to keep track of what I have. Do you have any suggestions?

PS It might also be useful to keep track of what I spend, but first of all I need to know what down payment I can afford, so that I can determine which mortgage I need to ask, for a certain house price.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Two accounts and some shares doesn't seem like that much work to sum up; if you had a dozen or more that were volatile perhaps it'd be different. Have you considered something like Mint.com? (It sounds like you want to track liquid capital, not earnings, incidentally.)

Comment: @ceejayoz "earnings -> liquid capital". Ok, corrected. Do you think "net worth" be more appropriate, or is the question title fine as it is?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate your life.  This isn't time sensitive information that must be accurate to the penny and time.  Your spreadsheet is fine.

Answer (score -3):

The two typical gratis solutions to aggregate one's accounts to compute one's net worth for that are:

- https://www.mint.com/
- https://www.personalcapital.com/

Notes:

- Don't give your true phone number to personalcapital as they'll spam you.
- Mint is owned by the Intuit company, notorious for lobbying to make US tax filing more difficult.
- They don't support non-US accounts.
- I personally prefer the Mint product.

Comment: The problem with these questions is that answers to them are opinion-based, incomplete, and may quickly become obsolete.

Comment: @littleadv those two websites have existed for many years. Tax regulations also sometimes become obsolete.

Comment: Mint, for example, has not been owned by Intuit until only a few years ago. You also failed to mention options which are not SaaS and are much safer and much more reliable.

Comment: @littleadv the ownership doesn't matter much. These two options are the most widely used solutions to view one's net worth and aggregate one's transactions in the US to the best of my knowledge. But you are welcome to write your own answer.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the fact that Mint doesn't support non-US accounts is a problem for me. I'm located in Europe. I added the relevant tag.

Comment: @DeltaIV you might also want to specify the country because some solutions are country specific such as bankin which is France only.